# jQuery insert element and overwrite

Tags: javascript, jquery

To empty a div and replace it with an image I am using:

```
$(this).html('');
$('<img/>', {
   src: 'blah.gif'
}).appendTo(this);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

*edit: I have to keep the `$('<img/>'` part in otherwise I could just do `$(this).html('<img src="blah.gif">');` I know!!

Comment: What have you selected for `this` and what relevance has it on the following line which starts a new search through the dom for the text `<img/>` rather than `$("img[src=''")`

Comment: @Lazarus - He's creating an element, not searching for one see [jQuery(html, props)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) for details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this using [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) or your current [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) with [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), it's chained but not that much of an improvement:

```
$(this).empty().append($('<img />', { src: 'blah.gif' }));
//or..
$(this).html('').append($('<img />', { src: 'blah.gif' }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/):

```
$(this).empty().append($('<img />', {
        src: 'blah.gif' 
    }
));
```